# ListView is showing rows with nothing in them WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-2008, listview

Hey guys. I am using a `ListView` with two columns to read a table off a `SQL server`.  So everything was right, when I had it a `ListBox`, but now that I changed to `ListView` and made columns something has gone wrong and the rows are coming in but there is no text, so it is just showing me a blank `ListView` that is scrollable.

Here is the `XAML` for the `ListView`:

```
<ListView Height="315" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="26,15,0,0" Name="listView1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="324">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Title}" Header="Title" Width="240"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Price}" Header="Price" Width="75"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

And this is the code being called on the `TextChanged` event to call it in from server table.

```
public void addtoList()
{
    cn.Open();
    String cmdString = "Select Title, Price from tblCart";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdString, cn);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    double subT = 0;
    double tax = 1.09;
    double total = 0;

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        int count = dr.FieldCount - 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {                 
            listView1.Items.Add(dr["Title"].ToString());
            listView1.Items.Add(dr["Price"].ToString());
            subT += Convert.ToDouble(dr["Price"]);                    
        }                
    }

    total = Convert.ToDouble(subT * tax);
    subTotal.Text = subT.ToString();
    totalBlk.Text = total.ToString();
    cn.Close();
}
```

Any information on how to fix this will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are adding a row for each column.   ListViewItem does not have custom properties.  You will need to create a class or stuct to hold your properties Title and Price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a custom object like following code,

```
public class CustomItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Price{ get; set; }
}
```

and then add the custom item to the list

```
listView1.Items.Add(new CustomItem{Title =dr["Title"].ToString(), Price=dr["Price"].ToString()});
```

Comment: thanks for accepting. and hope you will vote the answer when you are eligible to vote :)

Answer (score 0):

You are adding items to the listview collection.  Bind the listview's items source to the data table of the result:

```
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adp.Fill(ds);


listView1.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0];
```